# Error #1009 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

**This question is still open, no viable answer has been found as far as I'm aware. I've tested the only current answers with no result. If you do plan on answering I ask that you first look at the solutions proposed, as I cannot get it to work.**

update: Ok I think I'm onto this one, the only block that does not send the error is the block at the very bottom of the checkforhit function, till trying to figure out what that means.

```
 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at impossible_fla::MainTimeline/checkForHit()
```

so I recently created a project with a timer on one frame, but for some reason the remove event listener isn't working.

Here is the error text
    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
        at impossible_fla::MainTimeline/checkForHit()

Even though I did removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit); ?

```
stop();
var currentObject:MovieClip = null;
var dragging:Boolean = false;
initDrag(block1);
initDrag(block2);
initDrag(block3);
initDrag(block4);
var TCount:Number = 50;
var TTimer:Timer = new Timer(100,TCount);
TTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Tcountdown);
function Tcountdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    if (TCount == 1)
    {
        trace("done");
        TTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Tcountdown);
        gotoAndStop("lose");



    }
    else
    {
        Queen.alpha +=  0.02;
        TCount--;
        trace(TCount);
    }
}

function initDrag(obj:MovieClip )
{
    obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startADrag);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopADrag);
}
function endDrag(obj:MovieClip )
{

    obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startADrag);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopADrag);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);

}
function startADrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    currentObject = (MovieClip)(e.target);
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,stage.stageWidth - currentObject.width,stage.stageHeight - currentObject.height + 100);
    currentObject.startDrag(false,rect);
    dragging = true;

}
function stopADrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (currentObject != null)
    {

        dragging = false;

        currentObject.stopDrag();
    }
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);
function checkForHit(e:Event):void
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        if (block2.hitTestObject(dragtest))
        {
            endDrag(block2);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);


            TTimer.start();

        }
        if (block3.hitTestObject(dragtest))
        {

            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);

            endDrag(block3);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);

            gotoAndStop("lose");

        }
        if (block4.hitTestObject(dragtest))
        {
            endDrag(block4);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);

            gotoAndStop("lose");
        }
        if (block1.hitTestObject(dragtest))
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForHit);


            endDrag(block1);

            gotoAndStop("lose");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured it out I just had to create a workaround so that a variable is true for each thing that hits. Then have something test the variables for true. Reaaaaaly stupid error will post code later.

Answer (score 1):

you can check, if TTimer object exist and then remove event listener

```
if(TTimer)
{
    TTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Tcountdown);
}
```

Comment: How does this fix the 1009? Sorry I'm a noob. I implemented this and it didn't change anything.

Comment: it checks if TTimer is null, if it's null does not enter in this if case and don't add removeListener function on nill object reference

Comment: you try to call method of null object reference and my code check if object is null if it's it don't call this function and if it's it call

Comment: Where should I put this code? I tried adding it but it changed nothing.

Comment: where you add removeEventListner function on TTimer object

Comment: Can you maybe just copy and paste your whole code in? This sounds like the stupidest issue I've ever encountered but mine just isn't working.

Comment: lool :D your movieclips is undefined and you told me that problem is at Timer :D

Comment: Sorry I wasted your time, I'm an amature.

Answer (score 1):

`Queen`, `block1`, `block2`, `block3` and `block4` are `null` or otherwise `undefined`. No amount of fiddling with the timer will fix this. Check your instance names, ensure the objects you're referring to are on the same frame as the code being executed.

Comment: all the objects are there the issue appears to be the function checkForHit() running after I change frames, even though I already removed it.

Comment: @Flashdace Well there you have it. Remove the event listener before calling `gotoAndStop`. I'd do in in the line before `gotoAndStop` and not rely on it via some complex path.

Comment: already tried that didn't fix it, but I think I'm onto this one, the only block that does not send the error is the block at the very bottom of the checkforhit function. Still trying to figure out what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should simplify your checkForHit function

```
function checkForHit(e:Event):void
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        if (block2.hitTestObject(dragtest)) 
        {
            endDrag(block2);
            TTimer.start();
        }
        else 
        {
            if (block1.hitTestObject(dragtest))
            {
                endDrag(block1);
            }
            if (block3.hitTestObject(dragtest))
            {
                endDrag(block3);
            }
            if (block4.hitTestObject(dragtest))
            {
                endDrag(block4);
            }
            gotoAndStop("lose");
        }
        // removeEventListener here is not needed because it is within endDrag()
    }
}
```

Comment: @C Parcell Yep this would work although I would have to make the listener something like `addEventListener(Event.Collision Event, checkForHit);`so that it's executed instantly when dragging is true. I have no idea where I can find the list of actionscript events so yea.